# Is there any way to keep the total number of rows which contain a text?

Tags: r

In a data frame we have this format:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text_en_1 = c("Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon"), text_en_2 = c("Amazon", "Yahoo", "NA"), text_en_3 = c("Ieekkj","NA","NA"))
```

NA in this data frame is a missing value not a text. I just insert it to show the missing value.

How is it possible to could for every row using the id column how many columns have a value.

Example expected out put

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), number_of_columns_with_text = c(3,2,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.frame(id = df[,1], number_of_columns_with_text = rowSums(!is.na(df[,-1])))
```